# Qt Creator IDE appears to be falsely marking reinterpret_cast<::GlobalType> as invalid

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, reinterpret-cast, global-namespace

I am currently in the process of moving a number of class files from our Visual Studio source environment into Qt Creator (version 3.4.2).

I have made several changes to cater for the differences in the compiler (into MinGW).  One thing that is puzzling me is that the the IDE is reporting a specific error (red underline) but still compiles fine.

I am pretty sure the issue is isolated to using `reinterpret_cast<T>` where `T` is a global namespace.

For example, the following line will show as incorrect in the IDE but will still compile:

```
::GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, reinterpret_cast<::LPDWORD>(&processId));
```

The tooltip states:

> expected ';' got ':'

If I change the code to remove `::` from `LPDWORD` the syntax highlighting disappears.  This will be fine in the IDE:

```
::GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, reinterpret_cast<LPDWORD>(&processId));
```

I suspect this is a bug in the IDE.  Is this a safe assumption?

I don't plan on changing the code style for using the global namespace.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but probably the error is caused by the digraph `<:`. Make a space between `<` and `::` and check if it helps. Also, without this space the code will fail to compile. More on digraps here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C

Comment: @lisyarus Adding the space seemed to help with the IDE complaint and it compiles

Comment: Qt Creator uses its own C++ parser by default. This parser isn't a full, standards-compliant C++ parser by necessity. You can try out the experimental LLVM-based code model instead, it should accept anything that LLVM will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to lisyarus's comment, I was able to find that this is in fact a bug in QT Creator.  There is already a bug report [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-14731).

As I mentioned in the question, the bug doesn't stop you from compiling the code.  You can, if you wish, add a space between `<` and `::`.